# How to find single largest value from all rows and column array in Python and also show its row and column index

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, max

I am new to python. I want to find one largest value from a grid and also show its respective row and column index label in output.The value should be absolute. (Irrespective of + or - sign)
My data structure is like image shown:
[My data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7ZLT.png)

```
EleNo._ Exat0_  Exat10_ Exat20_ Exat30_ Exat40_ Exat50

1000____ 10____   20___  -30____  23_____ 28____  18

2536____-20___   -36___  -33___  -38_____ 2____  -10

3562_____ 3____    4______ 8_____  8_____ 34_____  4

2561_____ 2____    4______ 7_____  6_____ 22____  20
```

I tried `(df.abs().max())` but it is showing max value for every row and only positive values. I want absoulte max value.

Expected Results:
[what i want in output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeS7B.png)

```
EleNo.: 2536

Exat30 : -38
```

Actual Result:
[what i am getting in output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icFQv.png)

```
Element No. 3562

Exat0:  20

Exat10: 36

Exat20: 33

Exat30: 38

Exat40: 34

Exat50: 20
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`numpy.unravel_index`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html) for indices and create DataFrame by constructor with indexing:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Exat0': [10, -20, 3, 2], 
                   'Exat10': [20, -36, 4, 4], 
                   'Exat20': [-30, -33, 8, 7], 
                   'Exat30': [23, -38, 8, 6],
                   'Exat40': [28, 2, 34, 22], 
                   'Exat50': [18, -10, 4, 20]}, index=[1000, 2536, 3562, 2561])
df.index.name='EleNo.'
print (df)
        Exat0  Exat10  Exat20  Exat30  Exat40  Exat50
EleNo.                                               
1000       10      20     -30      23      28      18
2536      -20     -36     -33     -38       2     -10
3562        3       4       8       8      34       4
2561        2       4       7       6      22      20
```

---

```
a = df.abs().values
r,c = np.unravel_index(a.argmax(), a.shape)
print (r, c)
1 3

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.values[r, c], 
                   columns=[df.columns.values[c]], 
                   index=[df.index.values[r]])
df1.index.name='EleNo.'
print (df1)
        Exat30
EleNo.        
2536       -38
```

Another only pandas solution with [`DataFrame.abs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.abs.html), [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and indices of max value by [`Series.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html):

```
r1, c1 = df.abs().stack().idxmax()
```

Last select by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df1 = df.loc[[r1], [c1]]
print (df1)
        Exat30
EleNo.        
2536       -38
```

EDIT:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Exat0': [10, -20, 3, 2], 
                   'Exat10': [20, -36, 4, 4], 
                   'Exat20': [-30, -33, 8, 7], 
                   'Exat30': [23, -38, 8, 6],
                   'Exat40': [28, 2, 34, -38], 
                   'Exat50': [18, -10, 4, 20]}, index=[1000, 2536, 3562, 2561])
df.index.name='EleNo.'
print (df)
        Exat0  Exat10  Exat20  Exat30  Exat40  Exat50
EleNo.                                               
1000       10      20     -30      23      28      18
2536      -20     -36     -33     -38       2     -10
3562        3       4       8       8      34       4
2561        2       4       7       6     -38      20

s = df.abs().stack()
mask = s == s.max()

df1 = df.stack()[mask].unstack()
print (df1)
        Exat30  Exat40
EleNo.                
2536     -38.0     NaN
2561       NaN   -38.0

df2 = df.stack()[mask].reset_index()
df2.columns = ['EleNo.','cols','values']
print (df2)
   EleNo.    cols  values
0    2536  Exat30     -38
1    2561  Exat40     -38
```

Comment: Thanks. But there are 2 issues in output. Every time the `EleNo. 3562` is displayed even if the row value is changed. The Index should change for respective largest value from column 1 to column 6. Also if a positive value is greater than -38, i.e. +45 for a speecific row, output is still showing `-38` as maximum value. I want the largest Numeric value

Comment: @AkshayK. - Added sample data, can you test my solution with it? Because if change data max or min, then it working nice for me. E.g. `df = pd.DataFrame({'EleNo.': [1000, 2536, 3562, 2561],
                   'Exat0': [10, -200, 3, 2], 
                   'Exat10': [20, -36, 4, 4], 
                   'Exat20': [-30, -33, 8, 7], 
                   'Exat30': [23, -38, 8, 6],
                   'Exat40': [28, 2, 34, 22], 
                   'Exat50': [18000, -10, 4, 20]})
    
print (df)
`

Comment: Thanks for it. Actually I dont want the largest value from "EleNo." column. I want to find the largest value from Column Name(Exat0 to Exat50). Only is corresponding Row value from (EleNo) must be diplayed. For your example array, I want output in form of EleNo. :1000 , Exat50:18000. Thanks

Comment: @AkshayK. - Now understand, adited answer.

Comment: For your only pandas solution, i am still getting the largest output  value from `EleNo.` Column. i.e. 3562. While finding the largest value, `EleNo.` column must be excluded. The Maximum absolute value from the remaining columns (i.e. Exat0 to Exat50) must be shown and only its corresponding row index from `EleNo.` must be shown along.

Comment: @AkshayK. - So use `df = df.set_index('EleNo.')` before solution.

Comment: This works perfectly for me. Only if there are possible duplicates like 2 maximum values at separate locations, I want to display both of them. Eg.   for the above array, @ `EleNo. 1000, Exat50 : -38` and @ `EleNo. 2536, Exat30 : -38`. Output should display both.

Comment: Worked perfect. Instead of 1 largest value, could you help me to display top 3 largest values in the array as well. Eg. for above **non edited array**, Output should be somewhat like `EleNo. 2536, Exat30: -38` , `EleNo. 2536, Exat10: -36` , `EleNo. 3562, Exat40: 34`. Thanks

Comment: @AkshayK. - Can you create new question?

Comment: I want to find out largest 3 values for the same array. Code you provided works perfect for me

Comment: @AkshayK. - More complicated like seems. So better create new question. Also whats happen if duplicated max values?

Comment: If duplicate, your new code is already showing 2 values. In that case for top 3 values,  output must be `EleNo. 2536, Exat30: -38` , `EleNo. 2561, Exat40: -38` `EleNo. 2536, Exat10: -36`.

Comment: @AkshayK. - OK, so please post new question with this.

Comment: Posted a modified question

Answer (score 2):

Use a combination of max() and dropna()

First create a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4,4))

          0         1         2         3
0  0.051775  0.352410 -0.451630 -0.452446
1 -1.434128  0.516264 -0.807776 -0.077892
2  1.615521  0.870604 -0.010285 -0.322280
3 -0.027598  1.046129 -0.165166  0.365150
```

Calculate the max() twice to get the maximum value in the dataframe, and then cut out the rows and columns with nan.

```
result = df[df == abs(df).max().max()].dropna(axis=0, how="all").dropna(axis=1, how='all')

print(result)
          0
2  1.615521
```

Finally, get the column and row value, plus the max value.

```
max_value = result.values.item()
max_column = result.columns.values[0]
max_row = result.index.values[0]

print('max_value', max_value, 'max_column', max_column,'max_row', max_row)

max_value 1.615520522284493 max_column 0 max_row 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you have forgotten to tell pandas that the column `EleNo.` was the index. After that point, things are simpler: just build a series with the max of the absolute value of each line, take the index of the max of that serie, and use it to find the required line in the original dataframe. Code could be:

```
s = df.set_index('EleNo.').apply(np.absolute).max(axis=1)

print(df[df['EleNo.'] == s[s == s.max()].index[0]])
```

Display is as expected:

```
   EleNo.  Exat0  Exat10  Exat20  Exat30  Exat40  Exat50
1    2536    -20     -36     -33     -38       2     -10
```

Comment: The diplay should only include `EleNo. 2356` and `Exat30 -38` The remaining must not be displayed.

Comment: I only want maximum value from the columns `Exat0 to Exat50` and its corresponding index value from `EleNo.` column

Comment: You should be using `abs` instead of `apply`